# Workspace Switcher animation/visual settings on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, workspaces

I've installed CCSM and Unity Tweak Tool. With the latter I can configure the amount of workspaces just fine, but it has no settings for the visuals.

I then launched CCSM and went to tweak Desktop Wall settings, which used to affect workspace animation/visual style, but any changes made will not affect how the `super + s` key combo zooms out and shows my desks.

I have a 4K three screen setup and when I activate the switcher, all virtual workspaces zoom out to middle monitor and cover perhaps 20% of the screen in the middle.

Where can I nowadays tweak the visual settings and animation? I want to see more and don't want to have a choppy zoomin/out animation.